# Git push failed: HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502

Tags: git, push

Each time I try to push a project file to my private repository, the error code below appears.

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconect while reading sideband packet
```

The local server for the project doesn't exist, so I'm trying to create my own personal repository and check the project file. The size of project file is about 10GB.

However, file clones are possible, but push ends with an error code.

I've tried to do below, but the error was not solved.

- postBuffer issue

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 52428800
```

this one did not work for me, so I thought that my project file is over than 10GB,
I tried to do with Git LFS. (but also it did not work for me.)

- proxy issue

```
git config --global http.proxy
git config --global https.proxy
```

- http version issue

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

It seems to be an issue of authority, but I don't know how to solve it.

Has anyone faced the same issue like me?
I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me how you solved it...

Comment: `HTTP 500` is a server-side error, but without further detail I can't tell what the exact problem is or who you would need to talk to.